# How to set Google Chrome in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set Chrome as my browser for testing with Web-Driver and set the chromedriver.exe file properly but I am still getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; 
for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. 
The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
```

I have already checked the path of the driver but still i am getting same error.
I don't know where i have made a mistake.

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
Capability= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
Capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);

browser=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),Capability);
browser.get(webUrl);
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Sorry if this is asking the obvious, but: Do you have _chromedriver.exe_ in your C:\ drive?

Comment: yes, I have this file with the same name!!!

Comment: You seem to be mixing `ChromeDriver` and `RemoteWebDriver`. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using grid and trying to access chrome from my windows system.

Answer (score 11):

Aditya,

As you said in your last comment that you are trying to access chrome of some other system so based on that you should keep your chrome driver in that system itself.

for example: if you are trying to access linux chrome from windows then you need to put your chrome driver in linux at some place and give permission as 777 and use below code at your windows system.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\var\\www\\Jar\\chromedriver");
Capability= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();   Capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
browser=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),Capability);
```

This is working code of my system.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this since the begin and it always work. =)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

For Mac -Chrome browser

```
public class MultipleBrowser {

    public WebDriver driver= null;
    String browser="mozilla";
    String url="https://www.omnicard.com";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void LaunchBrowser() {

      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("mozilla"))
          driver= new FirefoxDriver();
      else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari"))
          driver= new SafariDriver();
      else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/mhossain/Desktop/chromedriver");
          driver= new ChromeDriver();   
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.navigate().to(url);
          //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It was giving Illegal Exception.

My workaround with code:

```
public void dofirst(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Softwares\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS: 
You have to install ChromeDriver first:

brew cask install chromedriver

It will be copied to /usr/local/bin/chromedriver. Then you can use it in java code classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Absolute path of Chrome driver");

 driver =new ChromeDriver();
 baseUrl = "URL/";

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Comment: Please, provide explanations and avoid code only answer. Welcome to SO!