# automation test doesn't run in eclipse java chrome browser

Tags: automation, automated-tests, build-automation, browser-automation

I am trying to run the following automation test shown in the screenshot below but receive the follow error message. I am a beginner in automation and not tech savy.

What is the issue and how can I solve it. Please can you send me step by step instructions to solve the issue.

I don't understand the error message even when I go to the links I have no idea what to do do. Please help

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, ..... The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Mja.jpg)

Comment: You should at least post the version of selenium you're using, the test code, and error as properly formatted code.  See [formatting the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  Remember, this is a community of programmers, not "sort my error" service.

Comment: The following link has answer to your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689426/how-to-set-google-chrome-in-webdriver