# Java read file from resources from jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("----------Start------------------");
    URL resource = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
    System.out.println("resource: "+ resource.getPath());

    File file = new File(resource.getPath());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    System.out.println("----------End------------------");
  }
}
```

If I run this code from IDEA - all work

```
----------Start------------------
resource: /D:/javaHz/target/classes/test.txt
1
2
3
4
5
----------End------------------
```

Process finished with exit code 0

if I reun from java -jar - I get error

```
D:\hz>java -jar hzTest-jar-with-dependencies.jar
----------Start------------------
resource: file:/D:/hz/hzTest-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/test.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\hz\file:\D:\hz\hzTe st-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\test.txt (Syntax error in file name, folder name, or volume label)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I do not want use `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Can you explain why you're unable to use getResourceAsStream? Further, can you share the jar'files structure. (Expand the folders)

Comment: @ Eleazar Enrique I have  chromedriver.exe in resources and I need get path and set to system property: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","myPath/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: @ip696 Use the edit link under your question and put that in your question. What your question shows is not what you need - your question shows reading a file in Java, but what you need is to get the absolute path. Make sure that your question is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

`new File(resource.getPath())` won't work because `file:/D:/hz/hzTest-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/test.txt` isn't really a filesystem path.

Since the file is part of *jar* file (a *zip* archive in fact), there is no valid filesystem path that would point to it.

The standard way is to use `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");`. You'll either have to modify your application so that it can read from classpath resources or URLs, or use `getResourceAsStream()` to copy the resource to a temporary file on filesystem and then point to it.

Comment: I write in my questions -  do not want use getResourceAsStream

Comment: It is simple example. I need get real path and set to System.property after that

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. The cause of the problem still holds though, and I'm not aware of any other way to get contents of the resource. You should probably expand on *why* you can't use it.

Comment: Well there is no real path that you could get. The file is part of the *jar*, and there is no valid filesystem path that would point to it.

Comment: I need create like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926284/4781349 but chromedriver.exe I have in resources

Comment: @ip696 Make up your mind. Is it `chromedriver.exe` as per your comment, or `test.txt` as per your question?

Comment: Definitely. There's a somewhat major difference between reading lines out of a resource file and executing an .exe embedded in a JAR file.

Comment: But, I should not execute exe. I have to set the path to property

Comment: @ip696 You still need to extract it before you can do that. The system property refers to a file, and you don't have one. And reading lines from an .exe file has exactly nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to translate a URL to a absolute path that you can use outside Java is this:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

URL resource = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
String absolutePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toAbsolutePath());
```

This only works right if the resource comes from a `file://` url - if your application was built as a jar file, it won't work, as other applications cannot look inside a jar file directly.

It look a bit convoluted, and it is. To break this down a bit:

```
URL resource = ...;
URI uri = resource.toURI();
Path path = Paths.get(uri);
String absolutePath = path.toAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
File file = new File(resource.getPath());
```

Bzzt. Resources are not files.  You have a URL. Use its input stream directly.