# how to load binary db file from jars using slick in a sbt project

Tags: scala, jar, slick

I am developing a testkit package for my team. I used Scala and sbt (sbt native packager).

In this package, I want to include a binary Sqlite db file (`data.db`) to provide some sample data. However, clients using my package are not able to load this data file.

Currently, my project structure is:

```
└── testkit
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── resources
            |   └── data.db  // binary sqlite database file
            └── scala
                └── Sample.scala
```

In `Sample.scala`, I connect to the database using:

```
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
var url = getClass.getResource("/data.db").getFile
if (url.startsWith("file:/")) {
  url = url.drop(6)
}
val conn = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:" + url, prop = Map.empty[String, String])
```

This works when running the project itself. However, when I published this file, the url becomes:

```
/path/to/testkit_2.12/0.0.1/jars/testkit_2.12.jar!/data.db
```

Slick is not able to load this file.

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Is sqlite able to read a file inside a JAR/ZIP? I would guess not, so you'll have to "extract" the file from the dependency JAR if it's in a JAR and put it in a temporary folder for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java read file from resources from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938305/java-read-file-from-resources-from-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, seems I will follow suggestions in the comment and use a temp file instead.