# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class Login 
{
    static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\MMFD-3\\MYData\\chromedriver.exe");    
        String baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";                  
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
>   for more information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>         at newpacakge.Login.(Login.java:14)

Comment: Please add your code otherwise there will be no idea what is going wrong in this. Please add what steps you've taken to fix this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"though set correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476647/getting-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-chrome-d)

Comment: Have you tried using the link in the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Google Chrome in WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689426/how-to-set-google-chrome-in-webdriver)

Comment: What is the question??????????????

Comment: @demouser123 I did what you are saying but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance of ChromeDriver before setting the property. Can you try after making following changes:

```
public class Login 
{
    static WebDriver driver;   
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\MMFD-3\\MYData\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        String baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";                  
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
}
```

And make sure the chrome driver version is matching with your chrome version

Comment: My Chrome Version is 78.0 and my chrome driver version is 78.0

Comment: After making changes as per your code  I get 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool

Comment: how are you adding Selenium? You should have selenium-standalone-server jar added in the project.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the *chromedriver* excutable.

---

Seems you were pretty close. Within the class defination, you can of coarse declare the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance as follows:

```
static WebDriver driver;
```

But you mustn't instantiate it as you did:

```
static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Unless you specifically mention the *absolute path* of the *chromedriver* executable.

---

### Solution

You need to separate the initialization part from the declaration:

```
static WebDriver driver;
```

Initialize the `webdriver` as a instance of `ChromeDriver()` later as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\MMFD-3\\MYData\\chromedriver.exe");  
String baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
```